# Magento 2 What is the fastest way to get construction changes?

Tags: model, setup-di-compile, construct

Whenever I made any changes on the construction method, I need to do `bin/magento setup:di:compile` to get any changes on my code. It was wasting my time, how can I get any changes faster than have to run that command, please?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setup:di:compile` => `Generates DI (Dependency injection) configuration and all missing classes that can be auto-generated`

So whenever you change in constructor you need to run `setup:di:compile` command to generate auto-generated interceptor files in generated directory.

If you want to bypass this one for development phase you can edit it's interceptor file located in `generated/code/Vendor/Module/...`

Comment: Once I delete all files inside `generated` directory by running `rm -rf generated/*`, it works fine on a hello world site (example site), without me running `setup:di:compile`. Is there any affect if it's on a big site (real project)?  

But at the end of developing site, I always run `setup:di:compile`.

Comment: it wont affect anything unless you are on development mode, once you switch to production mode you always need to run di compile after every changes in parameters. You `rm -rf` trick would work on development mode.

Comment: I would suggest once you make your changes on production server then change mode to production

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.